# sed program, what does it do?

Tags: sed

```
 "sed \'s/\t/ /g\' "
```

Thank you! It is part of code like this

```
string cmd = "sed \'s/\t/ /g\' " + string(filename) + " > sample.clean";
            system(cmd.c_str());
            ifstream infile("sample.clean");
            if (!infile){
                cerr << "error loading file after clean-up!\n";
                return 0;
            }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It replaces tabs with spaces, but it does so poorly.  Within sed itself, `'y/\t/ /'` is better, but sed is the wrong tool and it is even better written `tr '\t' ' '`

Answer (score 1):

It replaces tab characters `\t` with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

it seems like it replaces tabulations (\t) by spaces. The g means that the replacement should not stop at the first match on a line.